# Getting html script when running a unit test in yii2 framework

Tags: php, yii2

When I run the test in the console, I am getting HTML and CSS code. The other tests are running fine I have issue only with this one... Can any one help?
thank you

This is my DemoFeature

```
namespace app\tests\fixtures;

use yii\test\ActiveFixture;

class DemoFixture extends ActiveFixture{

    public $modelClass = '\website\models\DemoForm';
}
```

and this is my DemoTest

```
namespace app\tests\unit;

use app\tests\fixtures\DemoFixture;
use website\models\DemoForm;


class DemoTest extends \Codeception\Test\Unit{

    protected function _before() {
        parent::_before();
    }

    public function _fixtures() {
        return ['demo' => DemoFixture::className()];
    }

    protected function _after() {

    }

    public function testDemoProcess(){

        $demo = new DemoForm;

        $demo->name = 'Sample Name';
        $demo->company = 'cloudadic'.rand(115, 54785);
        $demo->email = 'demo'.rand(115, 547).'@example.com';
        $demo->message = 'Sample Company';
        $this->assertTrue($demo->save());

    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe this HTML is error message?

Comment: it doesnt show any error the output is html and css code..

Comment: Show us that html and css code